# Creating a list in C# using a for or do loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a List in C# that will store my integer in a space in the list and then move to the next item in the list and run the equation again, storing that value in that spot in the list and so on.

I've tried running with a for loop, a foreach loop, a do loop. And I just can't wrap my head around it.

The output I'd like to get is

Mean?
5
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation
random calculation

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();

        private static double u(double minValue, double maxValue)
        {
            var next = random.NextDouble();
            return minValue + (next * (maxValue - minValue));
        }            

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int r = random.Next(0,1);
        Console.WriteLine("Mean?");
        int M = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int> list = new List<int>(10);

        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", -M * Math.Log(u(0, 1)));
            list.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));  //<--------------error
            i++;
        } while (i < 10);

        Console.ReadLine();          
    }
}
}`
```

Also, the spot I marked, I am running into an error with the formatting that I have no idea how to solve either. I've tried writing it as: `Convert.ToInt32` but it didn't work out. This was the error I got:

Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What was the input, `"abc"`?

Comment: Your code should work as long as you enter valid numeric value , otherwise you will get the exception.

Comment: "error" is not a problem description. What "error" do you get?

Comment: You could always make it a bit more robust with [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you expecting the output from `Console.WriteLine` to be returned back in the `Console.ReadLine`? `Console.ReadLine` is for _user_ input.

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" is pretty descriptive. The "input" isn't in a "format" that `Int32.Parse` understands. Example: `int.Parse("10");` is fine, `int.Parse("foo");` is not.

Comment: the correct solution would be to validate the input before tryign to add it to the list.  This way you can trap errors and request valid input.

Comment: Also note: anything you can do with a `while` loop you can do with a `for` loop. So pick which ever one semantically makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you never store the value of `M` again.  You set it once, and then use it in the loop a bunch of times.  So while you ARE storing your input into the list, what's displayed has nothing to do with that.  It only depends on the very FIRST time you input, which sets `M` for you, outside the loop.

I believe there's other issues too (where are you using `i` for example other than updating it, or is it JUST a loop counter?), but that should get you started.